# In Vim How to jump to last, second last or some n'th character from the end in current line

Tags: macvim

Suppose I have a string like

```
takeThisAsAFunction(someParameter, someNestedFn(furtherNesting(foo, oneMoreNesting())), someText);
      ^                                                                              !
```

Lets's say I have cursor at location `^`, and I want to go to second last `)`, pointed by location `!`, how can I jump directly to that.
Currently I do

```
$2F)
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: if you knew the function name, `/some<CR>%`, but that's not necessarily "faster", just easier to think about (find the close paren of the function call starting with some vs. second-to-last close paren). I think you've expressed the latter as clearly as possible

Comment: I mapped `%` to `<c-g>`, hence I'd do `%h%l%` but I'm not sure it's 'better'. Besides, `$2F(` does not jump to the character you mention in your example, which one is the one you want?

Comment: Oopsie, It was a typo, I will edit it in the question. I wanted to write `$2F)`, I hope you could understand the intent.

Comment: Well, this is still not exact. `F)` would put you on your marker, not `2F)`, that's why I wasn't sure what you meant. Sorry if I sound picky, I just want to make sure we're on the same page here.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `<c-g>` is `%` for me!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm never sure if I invert, so I must be wrong here actually, sorry about that.

Comment: I prefer use ; motion instead of number. So it could be $F);. Each next ; key press moves cursor to next desired character from the end. See :h ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" with `2F(` is the `2`: you need to count, which is easy in some case, but can be troublesome most of the time.

I see several brainless ways of doing what you intend:

- **%**: `%h%l%h%l`...

the percent sign jumps to the symbol that matches the one under the
cursor (e.g. closing/opening parenthesis), or the first closing
symbol after your cursor. Use `l` and `h` to go a level inner and get
closer to your search

- **/**: `/function_name<cr>%`

As pointed by [DBK's comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26541/in-vim-how-to-jump-to-last-second-last-or-some-nth-character-from-the-end-in-c#comment47164_26541), same idea as above, if you know the name of the function

- **f**: `f);;;`...

jump to the next `)`, then use `;` to repeat. `,` goes backwards.

- **/**: `/(,`

Using a unique sequence in search is a fast way to jump anywhere in a file

- **B**: `$Bj`

`B` jumps to the end of the previous `WORD` (i.e., sequence of characters delimited by white spaces), that fits your example perfectly.

- **W**: `WWWj`

Same as above, but jumping forwards by `WORD` instead of backwards.

#### Final thoughts:

Always try to get as close as you can and avoid using `h` and `l`, but don't force yourself not to use them. `h` and `l` are perfectly OK when you're right next to the character you're aiming at.